# Laravel + React using Sanctum for authentication how to access and refresh token

Tags: laravel, token, refresh, sanctum

My concern is creating refresh token API and executing that endpoint on each and every request.
Isn't that extra request for application. Is this the right way to do ?

Is there any better solution for bearer token expiry for Single page application.

Comment: You can setup a time in `config/sanctum.php` key `expiration`.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel sanctum from version 3 has `expire_at` column.
while creating token you can pass third arg as expire time.

```
$user->createToken('device_name', ['*'], Carbon::now()->addHours(2))->plainTextToken;
```

After that create middleware in laravel in order to updated `expire_at` column

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $user = $request->user();
    
    if( $user ):            
        $token = $user->currentAccessToken();
        $token->forceFill([
            'expires_at' => Carbon::now()->addHours(2)
        ])->save();
    endif;

    return $next($request);
}
```

Add your middleware in Kernal.php $middlewareGroups api section.

In above example token will expiry after two hours of user last activity.